# Error while reading id in Laravel and MySQL in Ubuntu 20

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, eloquent

I have an error in my database and I can not find how to fix it

when I list all users the table displays all users correctly, but when I select a single id in the same table always return **null**, but this only happens with some users

```
$users = Users::get(); // return all users

$user = User::find($id); // return null when user was listed before, user exist
```

how can I repair it?

my sistem is

- mysql  Ver 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
- PHP 7.4.11
- Laravel 8

Note: I downloaded the database to local and it works, user is displayed correctly...

Comment: are the IDs numeric?

Comment: Do you have soft deletes on the User model? If the user was soft deleted, I believe it will not be found with ::Find

Comment: IDs are numeric, and the model does not have soft delete

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way, **duplicate database**

in CLI of MySQL

```
mysql> create database MyDatabaseCopy;
mysql> exit;
```

run mysqldump

```
mysqldump -u root -pTuPassword MyDatabase | mysql -u root -pTuPassword MyDatabaseCopy
```

remmember no white space is required after -p